# Own jQuery plugin, scope problem

Tags: jquery, plugins, scope

I want to make a plugin, which is ment to work with plain objects - I can iterate using each on. Thus i want to be accessible through jQuery's global object like $.myPluginFn().

```
(function($) { $.fn.test = function() { return 1; } })(jQuery)
```

Executing $j.test() gives an error:

```
TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)} has no method 'test'
```

What am I doing wrong? Assigning to $.fn.myPluginFn works on the other hand.

Comment: is there `$j`? i think this is not really correct

Comment: in his case `$j` === `$` === `jQuery`

Comment: yes, due to prototype presence we had to change it to $j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you want `jQuery.test()` to work you should be using:

```
$.test = ...
```

instead of

```
$.fn.test = ...
```

The latter is what you would use if you wanted `jQuery(selector).test()` to work.

Answer (score 1):

the `.fn.foo` function gives a foo function to each jQuery Object. So if you create one you can call it like this: `$("#id_of_item").foo();`

you this is useful if yo want to manipulate items.

but if you want to create other functions you dont need to put into the jquery object.